# Issue setting up MySQL with OrangeHRM

Tags: mysql, xampp, orangehrm

I am trying to setup MySQL with OrangHRM using XAMPP, but each time it is giving me an error: MySQL shutdown unexpectedly.

[image]

I tried editing the “my.ini” file and change the 'max_allowed_packet' setting to a larger value in the server. But the error is persistent.

Please find below a snapshot for my.ini file:

```
   # Here follows entries for some specific programs 

# The MySQL server
    [mysqld]
    port= 3306
    socket = "C:/xampp/mysql/mysql.sock"
    basedir = "C:/xampp/mysql" 
    tmpdir = "C:/xampp/tmp" 
    datadir = "C:/xampp/mysql/data"
    pid_file = "mysql.pid"
  # enable-named-pipe
    key_buffer = 16M
    max_allowed_packet = 1M
    sort_buffer_size = 512K
    net_buffer_length = 8K
    read_buffer_size = 256K
    read_rnd_buffer_size = 512K
    myisam_sort_buffer_size = 8M
    log_error = "mysql_error.log"

    # Change here for bind listening
    # bind-address="127.0.0.1" 
    # bind-address = ::1          # for ipv6

    # Where do all the plugins live
    plugin_dir = "C:/xampp/mysql/lib/plugin/" 

     # Don't listen on a TCP/IP port at all. This can be a security     enhancement,
    # if all processes that need to connect to mysqld run on the same  host.
    # All interaction with mysqld must be made via Unix sockets or named pipes.
    # Note that using this option without enabling named pipes on Windows
    # (via the "enable-named-pipe" option) will render mysqld useless!
    # 
    # commented in by lampp security
    #skip-networking
    skip-federated

    # Replication Master Server (default)
    # binary logging is required for replication
    # log-bin deactivated by default since XAMPP 1.4.11
    #log-bin=mysql-bin

    # required unique id between 1 and 2^32 - 1
    # defaults to 1 if master-host is not set
    # but will not function as a master if omitted
     server-id  = 1

     # Replication Slave (comment out master section to use this)
     #
     # To configure this host as a replication slave, you can choose between
     # two methods :
     #
     # 1) Use the CHANGE MASTER TO command (fully described in our    manual) -
     #    the syntax is:
     #
     #    CHANGE MASTER TO MASTER_HOST=<host>, MASTER_PORT=<port>,
     #    MASTER_USER=<user>, MASTER_PASSWORD=<password> ;
     #
     #    where you replace <host>, <user>, <password> by quoted strings and
     #    <port> by the master's port number (3306 by default).
     #
     #    Example:
     #
     #    CHANGE MASTER TO MASTER_HOST='125.564.12.1', MASTER_PORT=3306,
     #    MASTER_USER='joe', MASTER_PASSWORD='secret';
     #
     # OR

     # 2) Set the variables below. However, in case you choose this method, then
     #    start replication for the first time (even unsuccessfully, for example
        #    if you mistyped the password in master-password and the slave fails to
    #    connect), the slave will create a master.info file, and any later
      #    change in this file to the variables' values below will be ignored and
     #    overridden by the content of the master.info file, unless you shutdown
      #    the slave server, delete master.info and restart the slaver server.
      #    For that reason, you may want to leave the lines below untouched
       #    (commented) and instead use CHANGE MASTER TO (see above)
       #
      # required unique id between 2 and 2^32 - 1
       # (and different from the master)
     # defaults to 2 if master-host is set
      # but will not function as a slave if omitted
    #server-id       = 2
    #
     # The replication master for this slave - required
      #master-host     =   <hostname>
     #
     # The username the slave will use for authentication when connecting
      # to the master - required
   #master-user     =   <username>
   #
      # The password the slave will authenticate with when connecting to
  # the master - required
  #master-password =   <password>
    #
    # The port the master is listening on.
   # optional - defaults to 3306
   #master-port     =  <port>
   #
   # binary logging - not required for slaves, but recommended
    #log-bin=mysql-bin


  # Point the following paths to different dedicated disks
  #tmpdir = "C:/xampp/tmp"
  #log-update = /path-to-dedicated-directory/hostname

  # Uncomment the following if you are using BDB tables
   #bdb_cache_size = 4M
   #bdb_max_lock = 10000

    # Comment the following if you are using InnoDB tables
  #skip-innodb
   innodb_data_home_dir = "C:/xampp/mysql/data"
   innodb_data_file_path = ibdata1:10M:autoextend
    innodb_log_group_home_dir = "C:/xampp/mysql/data"
   #innodb_log_arch_dir = "C:/xampp/mysql/data"
     ## You can set .._buffer_pool_size up to 50 - 80 %
    ## of RAM but beware of setting memory usage too high
    innodb_buffer_pool_size = 16M
     innodb_additional_mem_pool_size = 2M
    ## Set .._log_file_size to 25 % of buffer pool size
    innodb_log_file_size = 5M
    innodb_log_buffer_size = 8M
    innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit = 1
    innodb_lock_wait_timeout = 50


    ## UTF 8 Settings
    #init-connect=\'SET NAMES utf8\'
     #collation_server=utf8_unicode_ci
    #character_set_server=utf8
    #skip-character-set-client-handshake
    #character_sets-dir="C:/xampp/mysql/share/charsets"

    [mysqldump]
    quick
    max_allowed_packet = 254M

    [mysql]
    no-auto-rehash
    # Remove the next comment character if you are not familiar with SQL
    #safe-updates

    [isamchk]
    key_buffer = 20M
    sort_buffer_size = 20M
     read_buffer = 2M
    write_buffer = 2M

    [myisamchk]
    key_buffer = 20M
    sort_buffer_size = 20M
    read_buffer = 2M
     write_buffer = 2M

     [mysqlhotcopy]
     interactive-timeout
```

Any Suggestions?

Comment: What's in the error logs it mentions?

Answer (score 0):

My error logs is:

```
2015-07-14 11:39:47 25716 [Note] Plugin 'FEDERATED' is disabled.
2015-07-14 11:39:47 6368 InnoDB: Warning: Using innodb_additional_mem_pool_size is DEPRECATED. This option may be removed in future releases, together with the option innodb_use_sys_malloc and with the InnoDB's internal memory allocator.
2015-07-14 11:39:47 25716 [Note] InnoDB: Using atomics to ref count buffer pool pages
2015-07-14 11:39:47 25716 [Note] InnoDB: The InnoDB memory heap is disabled
2015-07-14 11:39:47 25716 [Note] InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use Windows interlocked functions
2015-07-14 11:39:47 25716 [Note] InnoDB: Memory barrier is not used
2015-07-14 11:39:47 25716 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.3
2015-07-14 11:39:47 25716 [Note] InnoDB: Not using CPU crc32 instructions
2015-07-14 11:39:47 25716 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, size = 16.0M
2015-07-14 11:39:47 25716 [Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
2015-07-14 11:40:08 25716 [Note] InnoDB: Highest supported file format is Barracuda.
2015-07-14 11:40:08 25716 [Note] InnoDB: The log sequence numbers     1665234 and 1665234 in ibdata files do not match the log sequence number 15437456 in the ib_logfiles!
2015-07-14 11:40:08 25716 [Note] InnoDB: Database was not shutdown normally!
2015-07-14 11:40:08 25716 [Note] InnoDB: Starting crash recovery.
2015-07-14 11:40:08 25716 [Note] InnoDB: Reading tablespace information from the .ibd files...
2015-07-14 11:40:08 25716 [Note] InnoDB: Restoring possible half-written data pages 
2015-07-14 11:40:08 25716 [Note] InnoDB: from the doublewrite buffer...
 2015-07-14 11:40:11 25716 [Note] InnoDB: 128 rollback segment(s) are active.
 2015-07-14 11:40:11 25716 [Note] InnoDB: Waiting for purge to start
 2015-07-14 11:40:11 25716 [Note] InnoDB: 5.6.24 started; log sequence number 15437456
 2015-07-14 11:40:11 25716 [Note] Server hostname (bind-address): '*'; port: 3306
 2015-07-14 11:40:11 25716 [Note] IPv6 is available.
 2015-07-14 11:40:11 25716 [Note]   - '::' resolves to '::';
 2015-07-14 11:40:11 25716 [Note] Server socket created on IP: '::'.
 2015-07-14 13:00:52 26796 [Note] Plugin 'FEDERATED' is disabled.
 2015-07-14 13:00:52 68b0 InnoDB: Warning: Using innodb_additional_mem_pool_size is DEPRECATED. This option may be removed in future releases, together with the option innodb_use_sys_malloc and with the InnoDB's internal memory allocator.
 2015-07-14 13:00:52 26796 [Note] InnoDB: Using atomics to ref count buffer pool pages
 2015-07-14 13:00:52 26796 [Note] InnoDB: The InnoDB memory heap is disabled
 2015-07-14 13:00:52 26796 [Note] InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use Windows interlocked functions
 2015-07-14 13:00:52 26796 [Note] InnoDB: Memory barrier is not used
 2015-07-14 13:00:52 26796 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.3
 2015-07-14 13:00:52 26796 [Note] InnoDB: Not using CPU crc32 instructions
 2015-07-14 13:00:52 26796 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, size = 16.0M
 2015-07-14 13:00:52 26796 [Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
 2015-07-14 13:01:22 26796 [Note] InnoDB: Highest supported file format is Barracuda.
 2015-07-14 13:01:22 26796 [Note] InnoDB: Log scan progressed past the checkpoint lsn 17276706
 2015-07-14 13:01:22 26796 [Note] InnoDB: Database was not shutdown normally!
 2015-07-14 13:01:22 26796 [Note] InnoDB: Starting crash recovery.
 2015-07-14 13:01:22 26796 [Note] InnoDB: Reading tablespace information from the .ibd files...
 2015-07-14 13:01:22 26796 [Note] InnoDB: Restoring possible half-written data pages 
 2015-07-14 13:01:22 26796 [Note] InnoDB: from the doublewrite buffer...
```

InnoDB: Doing recovery: scanned up to log sequence number 17389703
        2015-07-14 13:01:25 26796 [Note] InnoDB: Starting an apply batch of log records t0 database...
       InnoDB: Progress in percent: 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18  19 20 21 22 23 24 25 26 27 28 29 30 31 32 33 34 35 36 37 38 39 40  41 42 43 44 45 46 47 48 49 50 51 52 53 54 55 56 57 58 59 60 61 62  63 64 65 66 67 68 69 70 71 72 73 74 75 76 77 78 79 80 81 82 83 84  85 86 87 88 89 90 91 92 93 94 95 96 97 98 99 
      InnoDB: Apply batch completed
      2015-07-14 13:01:26 26796 [Note] InnoDB: 128 rollback segment(s) are active.
      2015-07-14 13:01:26 26796 [Note] InnoDB: Waiting for purge to start
      2015-07-14 13:01:26 26796 [Note] InnoDB: 5.6.24 started; log sequence number 17389703
      2015-07-14 13:01:26 26796 [Note] Server hostname (bind-address): '*'; port: 3306
      2015-07-14 13:01:26 26796 [Note] IPv6 is available.
      2015-07-14 13:01:26 26796 [Note]   - '::' resolves to '::';
      2015-07-14 13:01:26 26796 [Note] Server socket created on IP: '::'.
@McWayWeb